# Customize "install prompt" PWA in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

How customize this from default ? such as picture, title, description, background.

I had changed at manifest.json, but nothing.

[picture of random install prompt which I want to customize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mPjx.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This install prompt cannot be customized.

PWA api is designed in this distinct way to inform the user that the action has an impact on their phone and it's not just a popup made by a page owner.